# Android ListView with SearchView, Filtered search results do not direct ti the right intent

Tags: android, listview, position, searchview, onitemclicklistener

First of all I am a beginner so please bear with me for a moment here.

I am trying to create an app with a list of items. When you click on the item you go to a new corresponding activity. 
When I added a SearchView to filter the list items, the problem now with the filtered results when clicked they do not direct to the corresponding activity.

Can you please correct my code below or provide a better way to direct to the corresponding activity. Please provide as much details as possible. Thank you so much in advance.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private ListView mListView;

    private final String[] mStrings = { "Google", "Apple", "Samsung", "Sony", "LG", "HTC" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSearchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        mListView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mStrings));
        mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        setupSearchView();
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, google.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
// code to direct to the corresponding activity                    
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupSearchView() {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            mListView.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            mListView.setFilterText(newText);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did. Instead of checking for item position which changes when search filters the list, I am checking for the String value. It worked

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String name = (String) mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if (name == "Google") {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Google.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
// code to direct to the corresponding activity                    
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (position == 0) {
     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, google.class);
     startActivity(i);
} else if ( position == 1){
     // do something, sending to activity of choice
} else if ( position == 2){
     // do something , sending to activity of choice
}
```

Repeat this for how ever many different activities you want.

Comment: Sorry I probably was not clear. Now if we run the app and write in the search box "apple", the results will be filtered and basically apple becomes in position 0, so if you click it it will direct you to google.class instead